# How to check price data of a crypto token on decentralized exchanges

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, web3js, erc20

Just wondering how I can access accurate price data for a given crypto token on decentralized exchanges (e.g. Uniswap, SushiSwap, Bancor, Balancer etc). I want to implement a solidity contract that can take an exchange and a currency pair and return the exchange rate.

Comment: Easiest way would be to hit an API if they supply one.

Comment: I have tried using the 0x API which provides data for many exchanges, but it sometimes returns incorrect prices, which wouldnt work for my use case